# Find a sequence of elements $(x_n)$ in a Hilbert space converging weakly to $x$ with $\lim \inf_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||x_n|| > ||x||$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces

This is a practice exam question and I am hoping to check whether my solution is correct.

Take the sequence of standard basis vectors $(e_n)$ in $l^2 (\mathbb{Z})$. Then, $(e_n)$ converges weakly to $0$, since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \langle e_n, x\rangle = \langle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e_n, x\rangle = \langle 0, x\rangle$$ for $x \in l^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Observe that $||e_n|| = 1$ for all $n$. Then, $\lim\inf ||e_n|| = 1 > ||0|| = 0$.

Comment: $\langle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} e_n, x\rangle$ is not defined because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e_n$ does not exist. The weak limit exists and equals $0$. Some clarification is needed at that point in your solution.

Comment: So maybe a better way to make this argument would be, for $y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots) \in l^2 (\mathbb{N})$, $\langle e_n , y \rangle = y_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ since $\sum |y_n|^2$ converges. Thus, $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that edit.